# AWS Lambda Serializing Object in Another Module

Tags: java, json, serialization, aws-lambda

I'm taking on some legacy code and am trying to write a lambda to work on a function.

The function looks like

```
public Task doTask(Message message) throws Exception {
   LOG.debug("debug message");
   // ... more code
}
```

However, the parameter `Message` is defined (with getters and setters) in a different module (and passed in as a dependency). As a result I'm getting the error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred during JSON parsing",
  "errorType": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
  "stackTrace": [],
  "cause": {
    "errorMessage": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.mywebsite.messaging.Message, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@31610302; line: 1, column: 1]",
    "errorType": "java.io.UncheckedIOException",
    "stackTrace": [],
    "cause": {
      "errorMessage": "Can not construct instance of com.mywebsite.messaging.Message, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@31610302; line: 1, column: 1]",
      "errorType": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException",
      "stackTrace": [
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.instantiationException(DeserializationContext.java:892)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserialize(AbstractDeserializer.java:139)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1511)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1102)"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How is it possible to serialize this object which isn't even in my module?

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like com.mywebsite.messaging.Message is either an Abstract class / 
Interface. In this case : using @JsonDeserialize will resolve the problem.

Something like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = MessageDeserializer.class)
interface Message {
}

@JsonDeserialize(as = MessageImpl.class)
public class MessageImpl implements Message{
//write your implementation
}   

public class MessageDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Message> {

    @Override
    public Message deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = (ObjectMapper) jp.getCodec();
        ObjectNode root = mapper.readTree(jp);
        return mapper.readValue(root.toString(), MessageImpl.class);
    }
}
```

These links can help you:
[How to add custom deserializer to interface using jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387978/how-to-add-custom-deserializer-to-interface-using-jackson)
http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-exception

Hope this helps!